# Take a graph $G$, and identify two vertices to create a contracted graph. Can we bound the graph laplacian of the new graph in terms of the old?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Specifically, we have a finite graph $G=(V,E)$, with graph Laplacian
$$\Delta(x,y) = \begin{cases}  \deg_G(x) \text{ if } x=y,\\
-\alpha(x,y) \text{ if } x\neq y; \end{cases}$$
where $\alpha(x,y)$ is the number of edges from $x$ to $y$ in $G$. Consider the new graph $G'$ formed by identifying two vertices $a$, $b$ and contracting them to a single vertex $c$. Here, we allow multiple edges but not loops, so in the contraction we will remove any edges from $a$ to $b$ but not multiple edges occurring. It seems like we should be able to bound the determinant of the new Laplacian formed by this in terms of $\Delta$ but I’ve been having trouble getting anything.

I’d like to do this without the assumption of $G$ having bounded degree to be able to extend this to infinite graphs if possible.

Comment: The Laplacian matrix is singular, as each row sum is zero (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Properties). So it is unclear what you want to bound.